# Chamada de função condicional - função com 3 parametros em javascript

Tags: javascript

No código abaixo é necessário implementar as quatro operações básicas dentro da função executa(), contudo nao consigo realizar.

```
function soma(a, b) {
    return a + b
}

function multiplica(a, b) {
    return a * b
}

function subtrai(a, b) {
    return a - b
}

function divide(a, b) {
    return a / b
}

function executa(operacao, x, y) {
    console.log(operacao)
    console.log(x, y)
    // Escreva seu código abaixo
    
}
```

o que eu fiz e nao gerou resultado foi que na função executa() eu criei uma condição if para que ao chamar a função e ao colocar os argumentos, fosse chamado a outra função soma dentro da função excuta, conforme eu havia aprendido em aula. vou mostrar abaixo como eu havia feito porem não houve sucesso.

```
function soma(a, b) {
    return a + b
}

function multiplica(a, b) {
    return a * b
}

function subtrai(a, b) {
    return a - b
}

function divide(a, b) {
    return a / b
}

function executa(operacao, x, y) {
    console.log(operacao)
    console.log(x, y)
    // Escreva seu código abaixo
    if(operacao === "soma"){
        return soma(x, y)
    }
}

executa("soma", 4, 5)
```

Comment: O código funciona, só faltou colocar o retorno da função em uma variável e mostrá-la:  https://ideone.com/ZaU53o - E sugiro se acostumar a usar ponto-e-vírgula no final dos comandos. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto-e-vírgula e "funciona" (e tem gente que até ensina a fazer assim), mas colocá-lo evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Comment: como o @hkotsubo comentou seu código funciona, só faltou mostrar o resultado :) algo simples como `console.log(executa("soma", 4, 5));` ou como no exemplo que tem no comentário com uma variável que fica mais legível

Answer (score 0):

O seu código está funcionando e está retornando como devia, porém ele não está printando na tela porque você não colocou um console.log para que mostre na tela, caso você queira implementar ficaria desse jeito:

```js
console.log(executa("soma", 4, 5));
```

Para complementar gostaria de te apresentar uma alternativa aos condicionais para cada operação, existe um comando no JS chamado `switch` as quais ele executa um trecho de código caso tenha suprido uma condição especifica. Para o seu código em específico ele ficaria assim:

```js
function executa(operacao, x, y) {
    switch(operacao) {
       case "soma":
          return soma(x, y);
       break;
       
       case "multiplica":
          return multiplica(x, y);
       break;
       // Aqui você continua implementando o restante das operações
    }
}
```

Assim mitiga uma grande quantidade de `ifs` e `elses` dentro do seu código, caso queira entender melhor o funcionamento da função `switch`, aqui está um link para dar uma olhada.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score -2):

Basta digitar todas as funções if e depois tentar rodar o programa. Se tentar apenas a soma não dá certo. A sua digitação está correta.

```
function executa(operacao, x, y) {
    console.log(operacao)
    console.log(x, y)
    // Escreva seu código abaixo
    if(operacao === "soma"){
        return soma(x, y)
    }

if 
if
if
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).